# mapping function from list to data

Tags: haskell

I am looking at changing the [hnn package](https://github.com/alpmestan/hnn) to support different activation functions for every node in a network.

In particular, [this line](https://github.com/alpmestan/hnn/blob/master/AI/HNN/Recurrent/Network.hs#L108) and [this line](https://github.com/alpmestan/hnn/blob/master/AI/HNN/Recurrent/Network.hs#L93) use specific function (activation), but I am trying to extended that to support something like:

```
evalNet n@(Network{..}) inputs activations = do
    s <- foldM (\x -> computeStepM n x (activations!!N)) state inputsV
```

where `N` is the node id/index.

Currently I am a stage where I have my list of activation functions of the same length as amount of nodes in the network.

I need help (as I am lost in the package source code) to find a way to apply `Nth` `activations` function from the list.

EDIT: I have tried `StateT` approach using `tick` (from documentation) and using `zip` function, both give multiple executions per every step, so the final result becomes wrong

Answer (score 3):

For the map you may want something like

```
as = [(+1),(*2),(+(-3))]
xs = [4,5,6]
main = print $ zipWith ($) as xs
```

The fold is more complicated but can be done with using the same idea: Zip the inputs with according activation functions and change the function-folded-over to use the values of the incoming tuples.

However, I doubt you really need/want to change the fold. If I'm not mistaken the fold should just pass on the activation-functions list. So there's actually nothing to do.

Comment: So, would it be possible then to do: `zipWith activations $! zipVectorWith (-) (weights <> prefixed) thresh` instead of line 93 ?

Comment: I guess this makes sense. Tested https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rememmber/caf1401e60d7a99d48fa/raw/128b8780280bfd94f74baa1280c629fad0c6fb09/gistfile1.hs

Comment: BUT! `computeStep` in my opinion does not have ALL the data. Therefore list sizes would be different

Comment: Another option might be to use `StateT` to add the index counter.